# Unable to see the changes to my responsive navigation until I refresh my browser

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, toggle

I have a standard horizontal navigation menu at the top of my page. To make it responsive, I changed the layout to vertical on screen sizes smaller than 908px and use JQuery's toggle function to show/hide the horizontal menu when on a small screen by pressing a little "Menu" button. It works great everywhere except when I manually resize my browser window when the toggle is closed, the navigation changes to horizontal but doesn't un-hide. The menu bar is still set to `display:none`.

The website is [www.clampdesign.com/dev/jsdd](http://www.clampdesign.com/dev/jsdd)

This is the jQuery code I am using:

```
    jQuery('a.btn-navbar').click(function() {
    jQuery('.nav-collapse').toggle('slow', function() { 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work by using the jQuery resize function to check to see if the window was greater or less than 980px and changing the display of the navigation that way. In my testing this seems to work fine, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do this. I would be happy to hear alternative methods or if you see any problems in the way I am doing this. Following is the change I made to my code:

```
    // Toggle "Menu" link to open/close navigation on smaller screens
jQuery('a.btn-navbar').click(function() {
jQuery('.nav-collapse').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    });
}); 

// Check the size of the window, and adjust the visibility of the vertical menu accordingly.
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    var viewportWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth > 980) {
        jQuery('.nav-collapse').show();
    };
    if (viewportWidth < 980) {
        jQuery('.nav-collapse').hide();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you work with nav bar you don't toggle, yo must work with the height and `overflow: hidden`, so you must do the animation with the height without hidden with display:none at the end of the toggle animation.

another issue I see in your page it's with the `subnav` where is the `search` and the `social media` you need a `<div class="clear"></div>` at end inside of `header-inner` to prevent the float over the nav

update: [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/VBzSG/9/)

Comment: Thank you for your response, Zach, but I don't really understand your answer. What do you mean by doing the animation with the height? Can you give me an example?

Comment: answer updated, it's just a quick example, everything else you already can do it...